# How do I add csv data to my Hashtable? Python

Tags: python

I have a hashtable with an insert function and I am trying to use it to add data from my csv to the table.

```
 def insert(self, key, value):  # does both insert and update
        # get the bucket list where this item will go.
        bucket = hash(key) % len(self.table)
        bucket_list = self.table[bucket]

        # update key if it is already in the bucket
        for kv in bucket_list:
            # print (key_value)
            if kv[0] == key:
                kv[1] = value
                return True

        # if not, insert the item to the end of the bucket list.
        key_value = [key, value]
        bucket_list.append(key_value)
        return True
```

The hashtable and csv_reader are separate files in the project.  I can see the csv reader is working with the print(row) output.  Would I just call the hashtable class in the csv file with the insert function?  I've attempted to try h.insert(key, value) but when I print the result it always says none for any key I input although I can see the data being read correctly.  Hopefully I'm asking correctly.  I appreciate the help!

```
with open('WGUPS.csv') as file:
package_data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
for row in package_data:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a dictionary?

Comment: The assignment requires us to "create a hashtable from scratch" and then "load in the csv data to the hashtable with the packageID being the key and the value being the rest of the package information (id, address, city, state, etc)"